# How to set dash.js-2.6.1 video player to play just on a specific bitrate without using the related check box on player's control bar?

Tags: javascript, video, playback, adaptive-bitrate, dash.js

I want to control [`dash.js-2.6.1` video player](http://mediapm.edgesuite.net/dash/public/nightly/samples/dash-if-reference-player/index.html#) remotely so that I could make it play the video at a specific bitrate from the bitrate list it catches from (*.mpd) manifest file.
It's obvious that this can be done using the bitrate checkbox of the player located on control bar of the player's window, but I want to do this in the background,
remotely and several times during video playback.
In other words, I want to find out which function in the [source code of the player](https://github.com/Dash-Industry-Forum/dash.js/) catches the bitrate value chosen by the user on the checkbox and feed that function manually and remotely.

I will appreciate anyone who guides me how to reach my goal even through another method.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the MediaPlayer.js source:

- https://github.com/Dash-Industry-Forum/dash.js/blob/development/src/streaming/MediaPlayer.js

The function you want to look at is 'setQualityFor':

```js
/**
     * Sets the current quality for media type instead of letting the ABR Heuristics automatically selecting it.
     * This value will be overwritten by the ABR rules unless setAutoSwitchQualityFor(type, false) is called.
     *
     * @param {string} type - 'video' or 'audio'
     * @param {number} value - the quality index, 0 corresponding to the lowest bitrate
     * @memberof module:MediaPlayer
     * @see {@link module:MediaPlayer#setAutoSwitchQualityFor setAutoSwitchQualityFor()}
     * @see {@link module:MediaPlayer#getQualityFor getQualityFor()}
     * @instance
     */
    function setQualityFor(type, value) {
        if (!playbackInitialized) {
            throw PLAYBACK_NOT_INITIALIZED_ERROR;
        }
        abrController.setPlaybackQuality(type, streamController.getActiveStreamInfo(), value);
    }
```

Comment: Thank's Dear Mick

Comment: Would you please instruct me how to use this function?                                          I added these two lines<< player.setAutoSwitchQuality(false); player.setQualityFor("video", 0); >> aiming to make player to play with least bitrate but nothing happened!

Comment: The a look at onFragmentLoadProgress in AbrController.js. This calls setPlaybackQuality which cals changeQuality which then calls setQualityFor. This should give you a feel for the use and the parameters etc.